# MySQL backup - warning password insecure

Tags: python, mysql, security, warnings

I made this little script with Python to create a backup of a table from a database:

```
import subprocess
sql_cmd = 'mysql -B -u User -pPassword  -e Database "SELECT * FROMdevice;" > file.csv'
subprocess.run([sql_cmd], shell=True)
```

It is working, but I got this warning message: `mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.`

I would like to hide or delete the warning if possible.

Comment: You could put your password in a `.my.cnf` file.

Comment: @khelwood Which, if to be honest, will get rid of the warning but add nothing to security. If a malicious user have access to the command line they most definitely have access to any local configuration file.

Comment: @DeepSpace I'm agree with you ^^ If you have an idea it will be cool Thanks

Comment: @DeepSpace Feel free to suggest an alternative that doesn't involve having the password somewhere accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Get the password from input

```
import subprocess
import getpass

pswd = getpass.getpass('Password:')
sql_cmd = 'mysql -B -u User -p pswd  -e Database "SELECT * FROMdevice;" > 
file.csv'
subprocess.run([sql_cmd], shell=True)
```